# Materialize CSS examples are not working in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, css, materialize, blazor, web-frontend

I'm trying to use the materialize framework for css with a Blazor application, however, when I copy/paste some of the examples into a layout, component, etc I don't get what [Materialize](https://www.materializecss.com) shows on the example. There aren't any CSS/JS loading or console errors that can be identified in dev tools, but it seems like something isn't loading because lots of components aren't working as the examples show.

For example, the tab *indicator* that apperas under the active tab and hops from tab to tab when you select one.

layout page:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main">
    <nav class="nav-extended">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
        <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
            <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-content">
        <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
            <li class="tab"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a class="" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
            <li class="tab disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
            <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

## Edit

Looks like the `M.AutoInit()` isn't firing properly. Can someone point out where the best place to call that function would be? I tried a

```js
document.onload = M.AutoInit();
```

on the index.html page and a interop JS on my  component

```
@code {
    ...
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        JSRuntime.Invoke<string>("M.AutoInit");
    }
    ...
}
```

Neither worked but maybe I'm doing the JSInterop wrong, couldn't find a definitive example, similar to what I'm trying to do, in the docs. Any suggestions or pointers would be great!

Comment: You know about the existence of https://www.matblazor.com/ ?

Comment: @Flores I do, was trying to avoid using a library for more a hands on approach to working with components. That is a good library though.

Comment: this might seem like a trivial check, but did you add sources in `_host.cshtml` file?

Comment: @Hoshani No, this is a WASM project. I don't think you can use _host.cshtml unless it's a server one. The index.html does have sources added to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me(very important respect the async await, so if you have any errors the Exception is properlly thowed to your browser console)

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    if (firstRender)
    {

        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("M.AutoInit");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the static JavaScript file that is used to initialize materialize elements, add `AutoInit` method to load first on `DOMContentLoaded` event listener.

Consider this example that initializes `Materialize Sidenav`:

**In the Sidenav.razor:**

```
<nav> <!-- navbar content here  -optional  --> </nav>

<ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
    <li>
        <div class="user-view">
            <div class="background">
                <img width="300" src="office.jpg">
            </div>
            <a href="#user">
                <img class="circle" width="50"
                     src="user_female.svg.png">
            </a>
            <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
            <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">xyz@xyz.com</span></a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Sub-header</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

**In the main.js:**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var M = window.M || globalThis.M;

    function activateSideNav() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
        var options = {};
        M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        M.AutoInit();
        setTimeout(activateSideNav, 864);
    });

})();
```

**In the MainLayout.razor:**

```
<Sidenav />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m12 l12 xl12">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

Also make sure that Materialize libraries are referenced properly in the `_Host.cshtml`

```
@page "/"
@namespace Example.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
    <base href="~/" />
    <link href="css/materialize/css/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="css/materialize/js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```